# Tensorflow Copy Weights Issue

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow 0.8 to train the Deep Neural Networks. Currently, I encounter an issue that I want to define two exact same Neural Networks N1 and N2, and I train N1, during the training loop, I copy updated weights from N1 to N2 every 4 iterations. In fact, I know there is way using `tf.train.saver.save()` to save all N1 weights into a `.ckpt` file on Disk, and using `tf.train.saver.restore()` to load those weights from .ckpt file, which is equivalent to the copy functionality. However, this load/reload will impact the training speed, and I wonder if there are other more efficient ways to do the copy (For example, do in-memory copy, etc.). Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at my question, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547688/tensorflow-keras-copy-weights-from-one-model-to-another?noredirect=1#comment84092982_48547688

Answer (score 0):

If you could have your code/ more detail here that would be beneficial. However, you can return the session you're using to train N1 and access it while you want to train N2.